# web page as a scheduler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduler

I have an ASP.NET forms app that allows users to run some management reports. Some reports need to be run unattended on a schedule and I created a C# console app to run them in Task Scheduler on a server. The powers that be are adamant that there be one web based app that does it all.

How do you reliably run jobs on a schedule, say 11:00PM daily, from a web app? I see Quartz.net as an option for the scheduler, but how do you keep a web page up 24/7?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried these services? http://www.onlinecronservices.com/

Comment: @Kizz thanks, looks like cron is for linux, I'm on Windows IIS

Comment: Services listed there are ONLINE services. Meaning they are platform-agnostic by their very nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of what the powers that be say, you shouldn't rely on an ASP.NET app to be a scheduler. Have a dedicated service in the backend that retrieves the schedule from a shared database that the ASP.NET web app writes to (directly or via a data layer) and have it spawn the reports.

This approach

- avoids reliability issues: IIS worker processes may be recycled at
  any time - you would have to account for that which adds complexity.
- limits possible security limitations: You would have to add certain
  permissions to the IIS AppPool identity to allow spawning of these
  processes. It's better to limit the rights as much as possible to reduce the attack surface.

Comment: While I certainly agree that it's a bad idea, his question really isn't "should I?" but rather "they're making me, how do I..."

Comment: @Christopher Estep The answer is that you realistically can't. The powers at be could demand him to program a time machine and it wouldn't change the response, it is not feasible.

Comment: maybe I asked that incorrectly, is there a way to have a single code base to produce the reports, act as a web page and spit reports out on a schedule? could task manager launch it in a mode that just writes the batch reports? I know this is odd but I'm trying to keep an open mind.

Comment: @user1054539 The technology isn't designed for this. You would be trying to fit a very large square peg in a very small round hole.

Comment: What if he's given no choice? Some people have to work for management who won't listen and don't yet have the option for alternative work. Do we tell him, "it's a bad idea so we're not going to help you figure it out" or do we try to help him find a "working" method that will get his "adamant" bosses off his back?

Comment: thank you all. I have many years writing Windows based apps but I'm a web neophyte. It sounded like a bad idea to me but being new I could have been missing something.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep: In my experience, management will be more unhappy with a solution that doesn't work, even if you followed their directions to a tee.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Oh, indeed they'll be unhappy. No question. :) Were I in his position, I'd try to give them what they want while looking elsewhere. But my experience is that the Pointy Haired Bosses of this world will not be dissuaded.

Comment: If it were me and management doesn't really know what they're talking about I'd pull up the NServiceBus publish/subscribe sample and adapt it. That way you have a windows service for running reports without the threading/recycling/permissions issue, but you can still provide a web UI, which is what they actually want. A web UI, not a report process hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 4):

Running scheduled tasks from a web application doens't make any sense whatsoever. Either create a service that runs on the server, or schedule a task to run at certain intervals via the Task Scheduler.

Not to sound indelicate here, but whoever suggested that this should be done through a web application clearly does not understand the limitations of the technology.

Comment: @DavidePiras: It's the thought that counts :)

Comment: James, I think your post is what I'll share with management. succinct and polite, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You take the smug route:

Write the reports that need to be run unattended to a HttpHandler

Then write a service that periodically targets the service.

Then you say, "See! I met your requirements. All the reports are run within the asp.net web page like you asked." -- You just added something in addition =P

Side comment: You should try and demonstrate why their requirements are not realistic.

Answer (score 2):

You can make IIS keep an app pool up 24x7 without too much trouble -- just disable the timeout and the automated recycling. Then something like quartz could work.

That said, your management is not making much sense, I would try and hunt down why they want to do it in a single app and start knocking down objections in a rational manner.

Comment: thanks, if I can't argue my way out of this I'll give this a try

Answer (score 2):

While doing this on a website is not ideal or recommended..it is possible, given that the site is **always running.**

Here's a sample:
I'm creating a Cache item in the global.asax with an expiration.
When it expires, an event is fired. You can run your reports or whatever in the OnRemove() event.

Then you can set a call to a page(preferably a very small one) that will trigger code in the Application_BeginRequest that will add back the Cache item with an expiration.

global.asax

```
    private const string VendorNotificationCacheKey = "VendorNotification";

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    //Set value in cache with expiration time
    CacheItemRemovedCallback callback = OnRemove;
    //Expire after 15 minutes
    Context.Cache.Add(VendorNotificationCacheKey, DateTime.Now, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), TimeSpan.Zero,
                        CacheItemPriority.Normal, callback);
    }

    private void OnRemove(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        SendVendorNotification();

        //Need Access to HTTPContext so cache can be re-added, so let's call a page. Application_BeginRequest will re-add the cache.
        var siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SiteUrl");
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadData(siteUrl + "default.aspx");
        client.Dispose();

    }

    private void SendVendorNotification()
    {
        //Do Tasks here
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Re-add if it doesn't exist
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("default.aspx") &&
            HttpContext.Current.Cache[VendorNotificationCacheKey] == null)
        {
            //ReAdd
            CacheItemRemovedCallback callback = OnRemove;
            Context.Cache.Add(VendorNotificationCacheKey, DateTime.Now, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), TimeSpan.Zero,
                              CacheItemPriority.Normal, callback);
        }
    }
```

This works well, if your scheduled task is quick. If it's a long running process..you definitely need to keep it **out** of your web app.

I haven't had any problems or weird errors thrown with this method.

Comment: You realize that the above example is entirely dependent on a request, right? There's nothing guaranteeing that a request will be made.

Comment: A valid approach if it meets the requirements http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: Well, the event not dependent on a request. As long as ONE request has started the 'Application', it will keep running in the background. Cache items can expire even if no one is on the site. The event will trigger.